# How would I implement spike and slab priors for parameters in a mean function in Gpflow?

Tags: gpflow

I am currently trying to achieve Bayesian variable selection within the mean function of a coregionalised Gaussian process. The mean function is a linear model and I would like to specify spike and slab priors for the parameters of this linear model.

I cannot find any information on how to specify a custom prior for parameters within gpflow. Any guidance on how to go about this or if what I'm trying is possible or practical within gpflow would be appreciated.

I am working with gpflow in python. I attempted to create a Bernoulli prior for a variable (code below), but I'm really not sure how to go about writing custom priors in gpflow, so this is probably incorrect.

```
class Bernoulli_prior(gpflow.priors.Prior):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = p

    def logp(self, X):
        X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
        sumx = tf.math.reduce_sum(X)
        n = tf.cast(tf.size(X), tf.float32)
        j = tf.math.log(self.p)
        k = tf.math.log(1 - self.p)
        return sumx*j + (n-sumx)*k

    def sample(self, shape=(1,)):
        lis = np.zeros(shape)
        for i in range(shape[0]):
            lis[i] = np.random.binomial(1, self.p)
        return lis

    def __str__(self):
        "B(" +str(self.p) + ")"
```

Comment: Your `Bernoulli_prior` implementation looks like it should be about right (though I haven't checked the maths)! Can you explain what is going wrong for you ?

Comment: Spike and slab priors would require a lot of custom implementation, as the assumptions for priors are that they are differentiable densities. How were you planning to do inference? Some kind of MCMC?